# como contar json por url python

Tags: python

Hola muy buenas estoy intentando como poder contar todo los elementos de un json pero en mi caso tambien me lee el error y no se como podria hacer para evitar que no lo contase

Aquí dejo mi codigo:

```
import requests
import json





url= "https://www.habbo.es/api/public/users/hhes-1bcedfe2097d62e175fbb44ad802489/rooms"

r= requests.get(url)
habbo3 = r.text
habbo3 = r.json()
salas = len(habbo3)
salas=(str(salas))
print(salas)
```

En esta url no no aparecen los elementos:
https://www.habbo.es/api/public/users/hhes-1bcedfe2097d62e175fbb44ad802489/rooms

En esta url si aparecen:
https://www.habbo.es/api/public/users/hhes-1bcedfe2097d62e175fbb44ad8024849/rooms

Lo que necesito esque me diga un mensaje en el caso que no aparezcan, de lo contrario que cuente todos los elementos "name"

Muchas gracias antemano!

Comment: creo que te faltaria un if luego de que haces el parse del json y valides si te trae la key error.

Comment: `if "error" in habbo3: print("hay un error")`

Comment: Muchas gracias ya lo he podido solucionar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar un if para validar si viene el key error como dice @Christian y te quedaria algo asi:

```
# url con error
url = "https://www.habbo.es/api/public/users/hhes-1bcedfe2097d62e175fbb44ad802489/rooms"
# url buena
#url = "https://www.habbo.es/api/public/users/hhes-1bcedfe2097d62e175fbb44ad8024849/rooms"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()

if "error" in data:
    print("Error")
else:
    salas = len(data)
    salas=(str(salas))
    print(salas)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo tengo solucionado

Comment: Pero que sucedería si uno de las claves en el json dado por un url valido es "error"? te diría que hay un error a pesar de que el json es correcto. Podrías comparar dos diccionarios para ver si son iguales. El diccionario que debería de aparecer cuando da error es `{'error':'not-found'}`, por lo tanto la condicion podría ser `if data == {'error':'not-found'}:`. Si la condición da True, significa que hubo un error.

Comment: El problema es que todo depende de como sea cada json devuelto... Es posible que existan varios tipos de errores (y por lo tanto jsons distintos)

Comment: Yo recomiendo que antes de considerar este problema solucionado, hagamos pruebas con varios tipos de urls no validas y veamos el Json resultante de cada una.

Comment: @DanteS. Cuando se hace una api o un endpoint los mensajes siempre tienen algo constante, por ejemplo es una buena práctica poner como respuesta fallida `{"error":"nombre del error"}` o  `{"message":"mensaje informativo"}` esto facilita la tarea a desarrollados y usuarios, ya que estarhsciemd9 una validación por cada error no es muy elegante y mejor se valida algo general, por ejemplo que es un error

Comment: @christian En dicho caso, suponiendo que esta api tenga esa buena practica aplicada, una mejor condición sería `if(len(data) == 1 and "error" in data)` ya que será constante que el diccionario tenga un solo item y que dicho diccionario contenga de clave la palabra error.

Comment: @PeliculasYSeries A la vista de los ejemplos que suministras, parece que un criterio para determinar si hubo o no hubo error es que cuando lo hay el JSON retornado es un objeto (un diccionario en python), mientras que cuando no hay error es una lista. De ser así siempre podrías comprobar el tipo en vez de buscar la palabra "error" en la cadena.